Are questions about trying to make reverse engineering harder appropriate?
I'm wondering if questions about how to make reverse engineering more difficult are within the scope of this site?

Yes, sure. The expertise on making reverse engineering easier is the same as the expertise on making the reverse engineering harder. Just as Security caters to both attackers and defenders, RE.SE can but cater to both obfuscators and reversers.
